# Find ip address of server from client on lan?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, port, lan

I am trying to create a simple multiplayer game in java.  The multiplayer aspect works great when inputting the host IP address manually to the client.  Is there a way to avoid having to type in the IP address and find it automatically? I have the port hardcoded on which the two games would connect.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Periodically send a broadcast requesting other player(s) until another system responds?

Comment: I would inspire myself from actual games. You could either have a server address in a configuration files, ask the user to input an IP or retrieve the IP of the client and do a quick check in the network. You could have a server that client connect and give their IP to share to other clients too.

Comment: I have tried pinging all ip's on my network, and from there trying to connect to all ip's that responded, but this takes an immense amount of time even with a short timeout.